# Using Parseval's to Evaluate an Integral

Tags: fourier-series, parsevals-identity

I have done some exercises on the Parseval's identity and I think it's quite straight forward. However, I came across this exercise and it made me confused. I'll explain:

The function is $f(x) = \pi x - x^2$ on the interval [0, ].

I shall find the sine series of the function and prove that: $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^6} = \frac{\pi^6}{945}$$

Now, I found the correct Fourier coefficients and I get:

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4}{\pi n^3}(1-(-1)^n)$$

Perfect. Now, using the Parseval's I want to calculate $|b_n|^2$ and here is where the problem occure. The problem is the $(1-(-1)^n)^2$ term. I tried to evaluate it:

1. $(\frac{4}{\pi n^3}(1-(-1)^n)^2 = \frac{16}{\pi^2 n^6}(1-(-1)^n)^2 = \frac{16}{\pi^2 n^6}(1-2(-1)^n + (-1)^{2n}) = \frac{16}{\pi^2 n^6}(2-2(-1)^n)$ which is 0 for even n!

So what I get is: $$
|b_n|^2 = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{64}{\pi^2(2k+1)^6}, & n \text{ odd} \\\\
0, & n \text{ even.}
\end{cases}
$$

Now, how does that help me prove what I should prove???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since as you wrote

$$1-(-1)^n=\begin{cases}0\,,\,\,n\;\text{is even}\\{}\\
2\;,\;\;n\;\text{is odd}\end{cases}$$

so that your sine series is

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{4\cdot2}{\pi(2n-1)^3}\sin nx=\frac8\pi\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^3}\sin nx$$

And now Parsival:

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^\pi(\pi x-x^2)^2 dx=\frac{64}{\pi^2}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^6}\implies \sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{15\cdot64}$$

And finally:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n-1)^6}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{(2n)^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{15\cdot 64}+\frac1{64}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}\implies$$

$$\frac{63}{64}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{15\cdot 64}\implies\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^6}=\frac{\pi^6}{945}$$

Check the above so that everything's clear...and correct.

Comment: All clear! Thank you very much! Does this mean that my approach, where I first start to calculate |b_n|^2, is wrong? Do I have to evaluate the 1-(-1)^n first and foremost like you did?

Comment: @Zeeko I wouldn't say it is wrong. It is just not so maneageble and easy to work with if you write the expression that way. Last time I taught Harmonic Analysis I stressed the fact that it is always good, and sometimes really necessary, to write that expression in the shortest, clearest possible way.

Comment: I actually don't understand the step after "and finally". Why and how did you do that?

Comment: @Zeeko I divided the sum in odd n's sum and even n's sum, and then some basic ariithmetic. Can you see it?

Comment: I think your expression for $f(x)$ is missing the sine terms.

Comment: @RonGordon Yes, it is. Thanks, I shall edit in short.

Comment: @DonAntonio I see it but I don't understand how you can do that? For me it seems like you just added a term...

Comment: @Zeeko For any converging sum $$f(n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n\;$$ if the two series of its odd and even terms converge  and the order of the sums doesn't matter (as happens in your case because of absolute convergence), we can write $$f(n)=\sum_{n=1}a_{2n-1} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{2n}=a_1+a_3+a_5+\ldots+a_2+a_4+a_6... \; ...$$ We are just adding first the odd indexed terms in one series and then in the other series the even indexed terms...